# Make windows font work in linux Mint and vice versa

Tags: windows-8.1, fonts, linux-mint

**Before begin : I Know that some windows font are under licenses**

So, as a java website maker I have on my computer Linux Mint 17 and Windows 8.1 I switch very often between the two and also I try to keep my computer update so I nearly format every 8 months to try some others distro but I have a little Hardisk and I try keep most space as possible.

I had find a way to get windows font work in linux by a simple ln but I'd like to have all my custom font (and sometimes system fonts) in maybe one shared folders between my two OS because i'm tired of two things :

- Reinstall fonts after all my OS wipes
- Switch between windows and linux because I have the font on one and
  not the other and I can't just copy to the other os because my
  partition is nearly full

Is there anyway to solve my problem because I googled this for 2 days and I find nothing...

Comment: How many fonts do you have that you're running short of disk space for them?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution (warning: untested!):

1. Move all fonts (*.TTF, *.OTF etc.) to your Windows\Fonts directory
2. Create a symbolic link in Linux as follows:

   `sudo ln -s /path/to/windows/fonts /usr/share/fonts/fontfiles`
3. Update your Linux font cache using `sudo fc-cache -fv` and see if the fonts are accessible

Comment: I don't know if Windows will take kindly to a similar symbolic/hard link (using *mklink*) to a custom fonts folder. If yes then you can possibly have one common fonts folder for both OSes on a third small (FAT32) partition. That would solve your first problem of having to reinstall fonts after all your OS wipes.

Comment: I will try your solution soon. I just hope that mklink will work correctly on system folder and that entries will be written in windows registry

Comment: @Skynniman: Try the Linux approach mentioned above first. That's more likely to work.

Comment: This where already done for me but it was only an half of my problem

Comment: @Skynniman: Ok, then try mklink to relocate Windows\Fonts and see if it works, then let us know too. :)

Comment: Did not work entirely, some windows fonts did not want to work. but I've got the one that I need which is nice =)